# "Can't call method "size" on an undefined value

Tags: perl

I wrote a perl script in which I'm getting the error "Can't call method "size" on an undefined value at userAccessLogMon.pl line 49." Below are the script that I'm trying to execute. I'm new to Perl and running the script as a part of testing. Any guidance on this error will be helpful.

These scripts are currently using as part of migration to AWS.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::stat;
use File::Basename;
use Time::localtime;


my $dirname = dirname(__FILE__);
my $name = basename($0);
my $json_file = "$dirname/$name.json";

#open (FILE, "> $json_file") || die "problem opening $json_file\n";
#close (FILE);

my $config_file = "$dirname/userAccessLogMon.conf";
my ($enabled,$run_counter, $source_log, $byte_offset, $line, $log_line, $log_type)="";


open (my $fh_config, "<",$config_file) or die("Could not open Config File");
my @all_lines;
my $criticals;
@all_lines = <$fh_config>;
for my $index (0..$#all_lines)
{
if ($all_lines[$index]  =~ m/GENGREP/)
{
            chomp $all_lines[$index];
            ($enabled, $log_type) = split('#',substr($all_lines[$index],8));
    }
    elsif ($all_lines[$index]  =~ m/CRITGREP/)
    {
            chomp $all_lines[$index];
            $criticals .= substr($all_lines[$index],9);
    }
}
$criticals= substr($criticals,0,-1);
if ( $enabled eq 'Y')
{
my $config_file_seek = "$dirname/seek_userAccessLogMon.conf";
open (my $fh_config_seek,"<",$config_file_seek) or die("Could not open Config Seek File");
foreach $line (<$fh_config_seek>)
{
        chomp($line);
        ($source_log, $byte_offset) =split('#',$line);
}
close $fh_config_seek;
my $out_file_crit = "$dirname/userAccessLogMon.out";
my $fh_log, $fh_crit;
open ($fh_crit, ">", $out_file_crit);
my $file_size = stat($source_log)->size;
if ($file_size < $byte_offset)
{
        $byte_offset = 0;
}
open ($fh_log,"<",$source_log);
seek $fh_log, $byte_offset, SEEK_SET;
while ($log_line = <$fh_log>)
{
    if ($log_line =~ m/$criticals/)
    {      # print "$log_line";
            print $fh_crit $log_line;
    }
}
close $fh_log, $fh_warn, $fh_crit, $fh_config, $fh_config_seek;
`find $out_file_crit -size 0 -exec rm -f {} +`;

$byte_offset = stat($source_log)->size;
open $fh_config_seek, ">", $config_file_seek;
       print $fh_config_seek "$source_log#$byte_offset";
close $fh_config_seek;
}
my $fName = "/datalocal/monitor/userAccessLogMon/userAccessLogMon.out";
my $TfName = "/datalocal/monitor/userAccessLogMon/userAccessLogMon.tmp";
if (-e $fName)
{
if (-e $TfName)
{
        unlink($TfName) or die "Can't unlink $TfName : $!";
}
`cut -d '=' -f2 $fName | sed 's/>//g' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{\$1=\$1};1' | sed 's/\\s/,/g'>> 
$dirname/userAccessLogMon.tmp`;
open CONFIGFILE, "<", $TfName;
            my ($confLine, $userID, $count, $metrics_data)="";
            $metrics_data="[";
            while ($confLine = <CONFIGFILE>)
            {
                    chomp($confLine);
                    ($count, $userID) = split(",",$confLine);
                    $metrics_data .= "{\"eventType\":\"DBS_Prod_User_LogOn_Dtl\",";
                    $metrics_data .= "\"UserID\": \"$userID\",";
                    $metrics_data .= "\"Server\":\"USNENCVL069\",";
        $metrics_data .= "\"LogonCnt\":$count\},\n";
            }
    close CONFIGFILE;
    $metrics_data =~ s/,$/]/g;
    open (FILE, "> $json_file") || die "problem opening $json_file\n";
    print FILE $metrics_data;
    close(FILE);
    print $metrics_data;
    unlink($TfName) or die "Can't unlink $TfName : $!";
    unlink($fName) or die "Can't unlink $fName : $!";
}
```

Comment: You'll need to track the value of `$source_log`, looks like you are searching by a line with `#` character but don't stop after found it (or not). Anyway, have a look in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [stat documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat): Returns the empty list if stat fails.

If you assign the result of stat($source_log) to a variable, you can then check that size is populated:

```
my $stat_result = stat($source_log);
if (!$stat_result || !$stat_result->size){
    ...handle lack of result
}
else{
    $byte_offset = $stat_result->size;
}
```